# EncodeURIcomponent is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, greasemonkey

I'm playing in the GreaseMonkey sandbox, trying to make a script that forwards loaded pages to another server for processing through POST. Here's the script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Mirror Page
// @namespace   mailto:linkhyrule5@gmail.com
// @description POSTs page to dynamic page mirror
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var ihtml = document.body.innerHTML;
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5723/index.php',
    data: "PageContents=" + encodeURIcomponent(ihtml) + "\nURL=" + encodeURIcomponent(document.URL),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Somehow, I'm getting `encodeURIcomponent is not defined`, even though it's a global function and should be available anywhere JavaScript is. I assume I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: you need capital `C` - `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot that Capital C... Its like Camel-Case:

```
var ihtml = document.body.innerHTML;
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5723/index.php',
    data: "PageContents=" + encodeURIComponent(ihtml) + "\nURL=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Comment: Oh dammit, *really*? I feel stupid now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was it. >.> Dumb mistake. I'll accept your answer as soon as I doublecheck.

Comment: Yup that was it. **headdesks** There goes my geek cred for the next month.

Comment: Tch. Can't accept for another seven minutes.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 were human. We make mistakes all the time. Even the best programmers. You just have to make of it